# A CSS animation that zooms in on image while hovering?

Tags: css, css-animations

For a school project I need to use a CSS animation in a website. I want to have it so that when you hover over an image, the image enlarges and becomes bigger. The only way I found to do this was with transformations, but those aren't allowed. Is there any way to do this with CSS animation, it can also be with Jquery. I'm just not allowed to do it with the CSS transformation function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can increase the size (width, height) of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```css
.myImg:hover {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.wallpapers13.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Cool-and-Beautiful-Nature-desktop-wallpaper-image-2560X1600-1600x1200.jpg" class="myImg" height="100" width="100" />
```

And you say that you couldn't use `transform` but can you use `transition` ?

**EDIT**

If you can use transition add this to my previous CSS part

```
.myImg{
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}
```